# Getting Tab ID or URL and displaying it using getCurrent

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

Here are my content script.js and background.html and error

contentscript.js

```
chrome.extension.sendRequest({"type":""});
```

background.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

  chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
           chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab){var urls = tab.url;console.log(urls);});  

  });     

</script>
```

Error message on the background.html console

> background.html:7   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined

This should be an easy change, but i'm stuck.

Comment: I've been having similar trouble I think.. however, I found a solution just using location.href from within the contentscript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot call get `getCurrent`, because you're not calling it from a tab context. The documentation says you cannot use that as well. You can only use this if your extension created a tab. An you want to grab its Tab ID to use it with extension [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html). There is no tab for the background page.

> Gets the tab that this script call is being made from. May be undefined if
>   called from a non-tab context (**for example: a background page or popup view**).

If you want to get the current tab id, you can use [`chrome.tabs.getSelected`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-getSelected) that will allow you to get its URL and ID.

Comment: getSelected is deprecated in lieu of getCurrent.

Comment: getCurrent does not work form popup unfortunately. it returns the popUp tab not the selected window tab

Answer (score 1):

Hm, it really doesn't work. I would like to hear the reason myself, but meanwhile here is a workaround:

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
   console.log(sender.tab.url);
});
```

Comment: Hi serg, that will not work because a background page isn't a tab, it is basically null. That will work if your extension opened another extension page as a tab.

Comment: @Mohamed Ok so like an options page, got it. Thanks.

Comment: Jup, Option pages work and other pages when you do something like chrome.tabs.create({url: 'extension_page.html'}); It is useful to get the id if you want to do message passing in an easy way.

Answer (score 1):

this can be tried

```
chrome.tabs.query({active:true, currentWindow:true}, function(tab){
      console.log(tab[0].url);
});
```

Comment: Could you please split this into multiple lines so it's more readable? A [docs link](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) would also be appreciated.

Comment: You should attempt to explain *how* your solution works.

Comment: Probably you are right samlev. But in this case, i have no a lot to say. I just played a little with API without too much investigation. Some things didn't work for me, and this one just worked :)